# Neo4j Spatial- get the distance between the start and matched node using withinDistance

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to get the distance between the starting coordinate and matched nodes in this query:

```
START n=node:stadiumsLocation('withinDistance:[53.489271,-2.246704, 5.0]') RETURN n
```

For every n returned, I would also like to know the distance from n to [53.489271,-2.246704]

I know that the results are sorted on distance but can I get the actual value?

Comment: do you find a way in cypher?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/IndexProviderTest.java#L281

```
@Test
public void testDistance() throws ParseException {
WKTReader wktRdr = new WKTReader();
Geometry A = wktRdr.read("POINT(40.00 30.00 )");
Geometry B = wktRdr.read("POINT(40.00 40.00 )");
DistanceOp distOp = new DistanceOp(A, B);
assertEquals(10.0, distOp.distance(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAVERSINE function to calculate the distance with matched node like this:

```
START n=node:stadiumsLocation('withinDistance:[53.489271,-2.246704, 5.0]') 
RETURN 2 * 6371 * asin(
  sqrt(
    haversin(radians(n.lat - 53.489271)) +
    cos(radians(n.lat)) *
    cos(radians(53.489271)) *
    haversin(radians(n.lon - (-2.246704)))
  )
) AS dist
```

The spatial plugin doesn't seem to have any method for this functionality.